# GROUP BY, but I want to see the last item

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have the following records:

```
Foo
FOO
```

I want to get a list of all records such that they are grouped by the column containing `foo` and `FOO`, but I want the last record to show instead of the first record. GROUP BY seems to display the first record.

```
TABLE:

id, name

Records:
1, Foo
2, FOO

SQL:
SELECT *,
       COUNT(id) AS cnt
FROM   table_name
GROUP  BY name
HAVING cnt > 1
```

The result is: Foo. I need FOO.

Comment: What's your query and structure?

Comment: -1 This question does not show any research effort.

Comment: @Polish - Would it help you understand my problem if I put table structure and SQL? I prefer to write simpler questions than bombard people with code, etc. It's not going to be so useful.

Comment: Yes and that you've researched some relevant topics

Comment: So you want to aggregate case-insensitively?  What you are seeing is MySQL's unusual `GROUP BY` behavior, which permits you to have cols in `SELECT` which are not also in `GROUP BY`, with unpredictable results.

Comment: Please post the whole table structure, and a few more example rows, because based on what you have posted, the result would be `Foo, FOO`.

Comment: There's not much more to it. I just need to get the last record versus the first record. If I had: Bar, bar <-- I would want "bar" in the results.

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie Are you using a case-insensitive collation?

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie Is the `id` column sequential?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski - no clue about case-insensitive collation. But if I search for "Foo", I get back "Foo" and "FOO".

Comment: @bluefeet - yes. It's an auto increment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*If* the id column is sequential, then why not just use a subquery to get the result:

```
select t1.id,
  t1.name,
  t2.cnt
from yourtable t1
inner join
(
  SELECT max(id) id,
    COUNT(id) AS cnt
  FROM   yourtable
  GROUP  BY name
  HAVING cnt > 1
) t2
  on t1.id = t2.id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/86f42/2).

If you just want the last row associated with each `name` and the `id` is sequential, then you can use a subquery to get the `max(id)` for each `name` along with the count. Using that result to join back to your table, you should get the correct final result.